# Как удалить пробелы в конце строки?

Tags: c++, c

Как написать функцию (на С/С++), которая обрезает пробелы в конце переданной ей строки.
Функция должна быть написана в расчёте на работу с очень длинными строками с очень большим количеством пробелов,
оптимизирована по количеству обращений к памяти.
Сигнатура: `void TrimRight( char *s )`

И мне не очень понятно,
что значит "функция должна быть оптимизирована по количеству обращений к памяти".

Comment: Учитывая, что строки в С не хранят свою длину, а имеют нулевой байт на конце, то единственный способ - бежать по строке и запоминать позицию последнего встреченного НЕ пробела. И как только мы достигли нулевого байта, т.е. конца строки - мы просто пишем 0 сразу за последним НЕ пробелом

Comment: Ну а под оптимизацией тут явно понимается неиспользование функции strlen ибо она что бы получить длину будет бежать по всей строке и считать байты

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void TrimRight(char* s)
{
 if(!s || !*s) return; // Пустая строка
 char *nonspc=s; // Тут будет указатель на последний НЕ пробел
 for(;*s;s++)
  if(*s!=' ') nonspc=s; // Обновляем позицию НЕ пробела

 if(*nonspc!=' ') // Вся строка могла быть пробелами, тогда nonspc->' '
  nonspc++; // Позиция за последним НЕ пробелом - там или пробел или конец строки
 *nonspc=0; // Теперь там точно конец строки
 return;
}
```

Comment: Ну, это _модифицирует_ исходную строку, что может быть (а может и не быть) вредно. [Например, кто-то мог уже посчитать её длину и запомнить в переменной.] Хотя обычно код на C такими проблемами не заморачивается.

Comment: @VladD А в условиях задачи сказано, что функция объявлена как `void TrimRight(char* s)`. Параметр только один, возвращаемого значения нет. Единственный вариант - модифицировать исходную строку

Comment: Хм, и правда. Тогда в рамках задания только так, как у вас. (У остальных ответов та же особенность, но ваш был верхний.)

Comment: Вероятно, вместо проверки на пустую строку, следовало сделать проверку на нулевой указатель.

Comment: Тогда его первым надо добавлять. А пустую строку приходится проверять, иначе можно записать 0 за пределы строки. либо эту проверку выносить вниз там где ++. В общем у вас конечно лаконичнее получилось, не нужно много проверок

Comment: @Mike согласен про выход за пределы в таком случае. Если убрать проверку на пустую строку в начале, пришлось бы добавить `&& *nonspc` в последний `if`.

Answer (score 4):

```
void TrimRight(char* s)
{
    if(!s) return; // нет строки (нулевой указатель)
    char* frs = s; // указатель на начало последней (самой правой) группы пробелов
    for(; *s; ++s)
        if(*s != ' ')
            frs = s + 1; 
    *frs = 0;      // задаем новый конец строки
}
```

Comment: IMHO это лучшее из 4-х решений. Только я бы изменил прототип на `char *trim_right (char *s, int *length);`. Т.е. возвращал бы `s` и заодно новую длину по указателю `*length`

Comment: @avp прототип по условию ТС фиксирован.

Comment: Она (или ее руководитель) просто не понимает, как лучше.

Answer (score 3):

Вот простое решение, которое обрезает пробелы за один проход

```
void TrimRight(char* s) {
   if (s == nullptr) return; // пустая строка
   char* space_pos = nullptr; // начало последовательности пробелов
   for (; *s != '\0'; ++s) {
     if (*s != ' ') {
       space_pos = nullptr; // не-пробел обнуляет space_pos
     } else if (space_pos == nullptr) {
       space_pos = s; // первый пробел устанавливает space_pos
     } else {
       // следующий проблел в последовательности, ничего не делаем
     }
   }
   if (space_pos != nullptr) *space_pos = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void trim(char* s)
{
    char* space_start;     //указатель на начало последовательных пробелов
    bool in_spaces=false;  //признак того, что мы находимся внутри таковой последовательности
    while(*s)   //цикл до конца строки (символа с кодом 0)
    {
        if(*s==' ')  // если встретили пробел
        {
            if(!in_spaces) // если встретили начало последовательности пробелов   
            {
                 space_start=s;   //запомнили это начало
                 in_spaces=true;  //запомнили, что началась последовательность пробелов
            }
        }
        else   // если встретили не пробел
        {   
             in_spaces=false; //забыли, что находимся внутри последовательности пробелов
        }
        ++s; //продвинулись на символ вперед
    }
    if(in_spaces)
    {
        *space_start='\0';        
    }
}
```