# Сравнение двух строк, одна с пробелом

Tags: c++

У меня есть функция поиска, но при сравнивании строки с помощью этой функции, `strcmp(mas[ii].street,pt)`, и тут возникла проблема, строка которую ввожу, выглядит типа так: "12345____"(___ пробелы), а которая находится в базе вот так "12345     ", поэтому показывает, что они не равны. Как можно привести вводимые данные к нужному виду ?
Может если в "12345" добавить пробелов до границы(допустим, 10 элементов всего, значит надо 5 пробелов, но как их добавить? )

Comment: *находится в базе вот так "12345 "* Смените тип поля с CHAR на VARCHAR. Пробел обрежется сам.

Comment: А какой вид - нужный?

Comment: @Эникейщик без пробелов.

Comment: @Akina: Что такое `VARCHAR` и откуда он взялся в этой теме?

Comment: @AnT Строка для сравнения - в базе. Раз она возвращается с хвостовым пробелом - значит, использован строковый тип данных с фиксированной длиной. Если сменить тип - проблема сама собой рассосётся.

Comment: @AnT 12345 это пример, в моем случае там лежит слово, типа "Дом" и пробелы до фиксированной длины, а когда я ввожу для поиска слово, то оно обрезано и в итоге не получается сравнить элементы

Comment: Правильнее будет обрезать пробелы

Comment: @Kromster как же их обрезать ?

Comment: Например, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487689